# To whom should I be addressing a custom close reason?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, custom-close-reasons

I voted to close a question the other day. It was extremely limited in scope unlikely to be useful to anyone else. It was a question that presented code and said "I don't understand why this results in X can you explain it?". It wasn't really valuable and not very searchable either (since it was about indexing but the title and description were entirely about loops).

It didn't entirely matching existing reasons. It's neither a typographical error nor unreproducible problem, but has the same problem of being only for the benefit of the OP. So I wrote a custom close reason:

> Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question appears to be off-topic because it is too specific to what the OP is asking and is unlikely to be useful to anyone else.

However, it didn't occur to me at the time that I've weirdly mixed this comment. It's posted on the OP's question and welcomes them to the site, but then I've written my close reason to address others who might also vote to close the question. The close vote interface implies that I should do the latter. But now that it's just sitting as a comment it seems like I should be addressing the OP, to tell *them* why it's considered off topic.

So who should this be aimed at? Close voters or the OP themself?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ideally, I'd say "**Both**".

The custom reason should indicate to other users the reason why you think it's close-worthy.

However, an additional comment (or longer single comment) for the OP as to what they could do to improve the question doesn't hurt.

There's no harm in posting multiple comments